# Set Up Google Analytics to Track Domain Alias

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

I found this article from Google http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55523

However I'm not sure what happens to the data.

Will I be able to determine which domain forwarded to the primary domain using their technique?

Or will it simply tranfers all the relevant keyword and other factors to the primary domain but not which domain was originally landed before the 301 redirect.

What I need to do is track which domain alias are being used.

Answer (score 2):

Using the technique as laid out in the documentation, GA won't show the original domain. One way to track it would be to modify the redirect to put the domain name into a URL parameter. You could then pick it up and send it to GA in a custom variable.